# Is there a tool to build and test an uncommitted/local change on multiple platforms?

Tags: version-control, build, cross-platform

A company I used to work for was plagued with build breakages. So they made a tool that would zip up the local, uncommitted changes from a developer's machine (which it detected from SCM) and send them to a remote server for a test build.

The remote server would update its copy of the source with the repository and then apply the changes it received from the developer. It would then build and test the changes. We actually targeted multiple platforms so it would do the above for each of those platforms. When it was done, if everything was green, the developer was reasonably confident they could submit the change without breaking the "real" build.

Are there any tools out there that do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at continuous integration tools such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). You can had slaves to target multiple platforms.

What you can do then is use branches:

Let say you let developper commit their code to a *development* branch (that can be the trunk also) that is monitored by your CI tool. When the build status on this branch satifies your criteria, you can then merge those changes to a release branch to commit them to production.

This merge can be done either automatically using your CI tool or manually when all lights are green on the dev branch.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually took a look at their plugins before posting this question. I couldn't find one that would let you submit a set of uncommitted files. That's the part I haven't been able to find anywhere. Do you know of one?

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to give that some thought. Ideally the branching and merging would be handled automatically by the tool. If it's too much trouble the devs just won't use it. Thanks again.

Comment: You can definitely do it using some automation in your CI tool. Don't hesitate to ask should you need more help ! :-)